# Esconder uma div quando outra aparece no ecrã?

Tags: jquery, css

Eu gostaria de esconder um `div` quando outra aparecesse no ecrã.

A div que pretendo esconder tem `position: fixed`, ou seja acompanha o scroll da página, no entanto, no footer tem uma parte similar a essa div e eu gostava de esconder a div fixada quando a outra estivesse à vista. Tentei o seguinte código mas sem efeito.

### CÓDIGO

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($('#footer').is(":visible")) {
        $(".socials").fadeOut("fast");
    }else{
        $(".socials").fadeIn("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Não funcionaria chamar um método que esconde a sua div e mostra a outra quando você torna a outra visivel?

Comment: @M.Bertolazo Como assim?

Comment: já dou um exemplo.

Comment: @M.Bertolazo Não são métodos que controlam, aparentemente. "Aparecer na tela", como citado na pergunta, remete ao fato de você rolar a página até que determinado elemento no rodapé fique na área visível da página.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ahh sim, entendi.. obrigado pela explicação, vou apagar a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma de fazer o que desejava

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var ell = $('#footer').offset().top;
    var ill = $(document).scrollTop();
    var screen = $(window).height();
    var distance = ell - ill;
    if(distance <= screen ) {
        $(".socials").fadeOut("slow");
    }else{
        $(".socials").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Primeiro vi a distância que o footer tem, depois vi a posição do scroll e por fim vi o tamanho da tela. Assim, mal a distância seja menor, ele esconde a div.